# How to find out specific columns of a binary matrix?

Tags: python, math, computer-science, linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have a binary matrix A of size 511 by 69495. Every column of the matrix $A$ has exactly 240 number of ones and 270 zeros. The inner product between any two columns of A takes the value in the set {104, 112, 120}. Now, I want to take out the columns of the matrix A, such that the inner product between any two columns takes value in the set {112,120}.
Any Idea how to take out those columns?

Comment: Are you using numpy?

Comment: @Fra93 ; Yes, I am using numpy.

Comment: let's say the matrix A is made of the columns `[a,b,c]`. Then if `dot(a,b) = 104`, but `dot(b,c) = 112` and `dot(a,c) = 112` , shall I remove column a or b?

Comment: Here, there are two issues if I understand correctly: First, to find those columns whose inner product value is 104, and then, to remove them. As far as the first one is concerned, the very first but perhaps computationally intensive thing that comes to mind is to iterate over the inner products of columns in the array (assuming numpy), and store the column indices (`col_ind`) if the product value is 104. Then, remove these columns by `np.delete(arr, [col_ind_1, col_ind_2,...], axis=1)`.

Comment: @hsaltan as per my prev comment, how would you decide which column to remove in my example? 'a' or 'b'? aka: which index would you store in your solution? Because in my example you could remove `a` or `b` or both and the result would be correct anyway.

Comment: @Fra93. I had thought of this too. But, from what I understand from Robin's text, and your example, removing `a` or `b` doesn't seem to make much difference because both satisfy the conditions that the existing information entails.  Unless further information exists to decide between them, removing any one of the two should settle. However, this proposed solution is not final, but perhaps, could serve as a starting idea.